# Listing GPA on undergrad CV when reaching out to professors

Tags: cv, gpa

I intend to apply to PhD programs in computer science, and I have been advised to reach out to professors I'm interested in working with by sending them my CV. My GPA is 3.6, which is not bad, but it's not great either. I think the rest of my CV/profile is quite positive, but I am not inclined to list my GPA for this 'reaching out CV', since it may create a bad first impression, even before I apply. So the question is whether I should leave my GPA on.

Comment: 3.6 is well above the threshold where the actual number matters; other things like research experience are more significant.  If your CV usually lists your GPA, leave it in.  If your usual CV doesn't list your GPA, don't bother adding it.  In either case, be sure to give some evidence of research potential/ability/experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While people may not care very, very much about undergrad GPA, if you send a CV *without* it people may notice (even if not caring deeply), and wonder about it, ... which is not what you want them to be thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Conspicuously missing a CV makes a worse impression.  The most important thing, in my view, is to take some time to properly understand what the professor is doing, and how you could help his/her research efforts.  A thoughtful contact of this type is much more valuable than crafting the correct CV/profile.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I do intend to be thoughtful in my contact with a professor. But my question is about whether I should include my GPA in the CV that I send.